# Restricting the file extension saved when using tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently writing a GUI in python using Tkinter where the user is able to save the state of the GUI in their directory with the extension ".espace".

`filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".espace")`

If the user specifies a different file extension then the file is saved with the extension that they specified. Is there anyway to prevent this? So that they are completely restricted to saving the file with the extension ".espace"?

Comment: Isn't it your code that is actually opening the file and writing to it? Can't you simply check the value of `filename` and raise an error if it's not correct. OTOH, if the user wants to change the suffix, shouldn't they be allowed to do that? It's their data and their system. As a user I would be pretty upset if I couldn't use whatever name I wanted. If they want a different name, all you're doing is forcing them to save it according to your rules and then rename the file outside of your control.

Answer (score 13):

You can specify file type by using the 'filetypes' option. The below example will change the file type drop down on the save dialog to .espace and all files.

```
filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".espace", filetypes=(("espace file", "*.espace"),("All Files", "*.*") ))
```

I have not found an option, using asksaveasfilename, to restrict use of other file extensions. I'd think you could write a loop that would force the user to use that extension:

```
import os
import sys
ext = ""
while ext != ".escape":
   filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".espace", filetypes=(("espace file", "*.espace"),("All Files", "*.*") ))
   file,ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
```

Comment: I know it's 5 years later, but this came up first in my search, so I'll add that excluding the `("All Files", "*.*")` and only using `filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".espace", filetypes=(("espace file", "*.espace"),))` forces the extension.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I know I'm 7 years late but you could force your extension my doing a simple if command after the dialog box, just add this simple line:

```
filename = filename if ".space" in filename else filename + ".space"
```

Basically checks if the default extension was used, if not it will add it to the end.If user types another extension it will be invalidated.

Comment: Two years later but this would not ensure the proper extension is used.

`filename = filename if filename.split(".")[-1].lower()=="extension" else filename + "extension"`

would do a better job

Answer (score 2):

In order for the solution of @IsraelJ to apply to different extensions and be resistant to upper / lower case letters, I suggest:

```
fileext = ".space"
filename = filename if filename[-len(fileext):].lower() == fileext else filename + fileext
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same bug and the upper solutions didn`t worked for me. To fix it, I added a default type and than everything worked as intended.

```
filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.json', filetypes=[("csv", ".csv"), ("Json", ".json")])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The [top-rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18041231/1519716) also used a a default type. After taking the comment by [tgikal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4777984/tgikal) into account, this answer becomes a duplicate.